# アイランド or 島 when translating an island name from English?

Tags: translation, words

There's an island called Bainbridge Island near me. I'm wondering if it would make sense to translate "Island" as 島, or if it would be better to translate it to katakana directly. Which is the better translation or should it differ based on the context? ベインブリッジアイランド or ベインブリッジ島.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net searching shows that both are used.

The Wikipedia entry quoted below suggests that the name of the island is ベインブリッジ島, and the name of the city (or town) is ベインブリッジアイランド.

https://www.google.co.jp/#q=%E3%83%99%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E5%B3%B6

- ベインブリッジ島の人気観光スポット ランキング 10選 - TripAdvisor
- Go Feisty – 日帰りで楽しむベインブリッジ島

> ベインブリッジアイランド (ワシントン州) - Wikipedia 
>  [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ベインブリッジアイランド_(ワシントン州)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89_(%E3%83%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3%E5%B7%9E))
>
> ベインブリッジアイランド (Bainbridge Island) は、アメリカ合衆国ワシントン州キットサップ郡にある都市。ピュージェット湾に浮かぶ同名の島（ベインブリッジ島）を範囲とする自治体である。2010年国勢調査によると、人口は23,025人である。